# Bubble Sorting a linked list, by names

Tags: c

I have a linked list, and I want to sort them by names
(for example the names "Bx", "Tx", "Ax" would become : "Ax", "Bx", "Tx")...
I need to switch the names if the one in the node's right has a "smaller name"..

this is what I wrote:

```
typedef struct data
{
char *name;
}data;

typedef struct Node 
{
data NodeData;
struct Node *next;
struct Node *prev;
}Node;

void Sorting(Node *head)
{
 Node *temp = head;
 Node *temp2 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
 while (temp != NULL)
 {
       if (1 == (strcmp(temp -> NodeData.name, temp -> next -> NodeData.name))) 
       {
              strcpy (temp2 -> NodeData.name, temp -> NodeData.name);
              strcpy (temp -> NodeData.name, temp -> next -> NodeData.name);
              strcpy (temp -> next -> NodeData.name, temp2 -> NodeData.name);
       } 

       temp = temp -> next;

 }

}
```

I'm getting an runtime - error on the part where I need to swarp betwen the node's name(the strcpy lines):
An access violation (segmentation fault)...

Comment: I wouldn't count on [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strcmp.html) returning `1`. You should test for greater-than-zero instead.

Comment: Allright, i've changed it, though it still does some trouble to ne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (1 == (strcmp(temp -> NodeData.name, temp -> next -> NodeData.name))) {...}
```

When this line is executed, there is no guarantee that temp->next is not NULL.
If it is NULL, temp->next->NodeData.Name would be rather painfull.

Also, as has been said, testing strcmp()s result against 1 is not right. strcmp can resutning any value equal to zero, < zero or > zero.

Also, as has been said, strcpy() is not right; the strings could have different allocated sizes, or could live in non-writable memory (string constants) . Swapping the pointers will suffice.

UPDATE:

```
void Sorting(Node *head)
{
 Node *temp ;

                /* since the compare dereferences temp->next you'll have to verify that it is not NULL */
 for (temp = head; temp && temp->next; temp = temp->next)  
 {
       if (strcmp(temp->NodeData.name, temp->next->NodeData.name) > 0 )  
       {
                /* no need for a whole node, since you only copy a pointer */
              char *cp;
              cp = temp->NodeData.name;
              temp->NodeData.name = temp->next->NodeData.name;
              temp->next->NodeData.name = cp;
       } 

 }

}
```

BTW: bubble sorting a linked list is really ugly. Linked lists are easyer and more elagantly sorted by mergesort.

Comment: then how can I switch the name from both nodes?
I've edited the while conidition for while (temp -> next != NULL)...,though it still does problems to me in the strcpy lines...

Comment: It works, but only in a certin order..
When I put the 3 names in the linked list like thos:
"Yoav", "Daniel", "Amit", it shows me Daniel, Amit, Yoav, and when I put it like: "Yoav", "Amit", "Daniel", it shows me Amit, Daniel, Yoav(the good way)...
Sometimes ,it doesnt do the sorting...

Comment: Draw it on paper. If you perform only one pass of bubblesort, not all wrong starting orders can be fixed. "CBA" will probably en up as "BAC" after one pass.

Comment: Yes, so somehow it only does it once... though I need to do it twice...
How can I change it to become twice then.. ? I dont see any option

Comment: 1) do it twice. 2) do it until sorted. 3) do it until no more changes. 4) look at other bubblesort implementations. 5) profit!

Comment: I've been thinking a lot, but I cant understand why doesnt it work untill all sorted...
can you help me a bit..?
By the way, I've wrote a sorting code that is similiar to you, just insted of a for loop, used a while one... and it gave me the same result... I bet it's something with the conidition, but I cant find what!
I know how to do a bubblesort on int numbers, and make it works perfect, but I've never did it on sorting names...
A help would really be great...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be sorting the list by exchanging the data values, instead you should swap the nodes themselves. Note that this requires you to return the pointer to the new first node of the list.

EDIT: Passing a pointer to the head of the list also works, if you're into doubly-indirect pointers. It can make the code simpler too.

Comment: It does make more sense to swap the nodes or even the `name` pointers inside the nodes. Anything is better than all those calls to `strcpy`.

Comment: How can I change it from switching the name, to switching the nodes ?

Comment: @AmitM9S6 You remove one of the nodes from the list, and re-insert it after the other node.

Answer (score 0):

`temp2` is `char*` here

```
char *temp2;
```

but `Node` here

```
strcpy (temp2 -> NodeData.name, temp -> NodeData.name);
```

So yes, on this line, you behave as if `temp2` was a structure or union, but it is not.

Comment: I've nothiced it a sec before you posted :P
I've fixed it, and it gives me a runtime error...

Comment: @AmitM9S6 Well... is this the whole body of function `Sorting` ? Because then `temp2` is not allocated anywhere, so naturally you're working with memory that is not yours => access violation / segfault.

Comment: I've been allocating some memory to it, though it still gives me the same error...

Comment: @AmitM9S6 But `temp2 -> NodeData.name` is still not allocated. You apparently don't realize that declaring a pointer does not allocate any more memory than 4 bytes for that pointer.

Comment: @AmitM9S6 No, you didn't. You allocated temp2, which has tree items `two `Node*` pointers and one `data` struct. The `data` struct contains a `char*` pointers, which points *nowhere* because you didn't allocate space for it. A `char*` is just a simple 4-byte pointer, you must allocate space for it to point to, otherwise there is no place to store your string in.